What's the function signature for Chainlink's CCIP send?
Chainlink's CCIP send function definition looks like the following:
  function ccipSend(
    uint64 destinationChainSelector,
    Client.EVM2AnyMessage memory message
  ) external payable whenHealthy returns (bytes32) {

So what's the function selector?

To get only the function selector of ccipSend(), you can use:
cast sig "ccipSend(uint64,(bytes,bytes,(address,uint256)[],address,bytes))"

Output:
0x96f4e9f9


"ccipSend(uint64,(bytes,bytes,(address,uint256)[],address,bytes))"
You can decode the hexdata of a ccipSend call with:
cast calldata-decode "ccipSend(uint64,(bytes,bytes,(address,uint256)[],address,bytes))" HEXDATA_HERE

